# How can I simulate a self balancing stick man?

Tags: simulation, physics, game-physics

A good example of what I want can be found here: https://dan-ball.jp/en/javagame/dust/

Just click the "player" option and then click on the screen, a stick figure-like player will be spawned that appears to balance by itself. You can also move it with the arrow keys. I want to do something like this for my game, I want it to seem like the player is actually balancing and could fall over but I have no idea where to start. I can't find any information on this at all.

How can I achieve this? Is there a name for it?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it fairly easily with Box2d (which is included in Corona, if you can learn to program in Lua). The player in that game example are so small that it's hard to see what they really look like, and the amount of simulation would depend on what you want to do with the guy. Just having it balance is going to be fun at first but then what? To sit, walk etc, or do karate like that fighter example in same game, that's not obvious: lots of time spent creating a library of motions and transitions. [StickMotion](http://www.hotjamdonut.com.au/StickMotion/StickMotion.html) website should give you ideas. Some free tools are "Pivot animator" and Stykz, but they are closed source. You might find [this codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110897/Stick-Figure-Animation-Using-C-and-WPF) useful. Try google search for keywords `"stick figure" animation "open source"`.